# LINQ to XML selecting root element with prefix

Tags: c#, xpath, linq-to-xml

I've got a simple xml document

```
<n1:data xmlns:n1="http://test.com/types" xmlns="http://test.com/basic" xmlns:n2="http://test.com/value">
  <n2:value>Test</n2:value>
</n1:data>
```

and I need to select elements in it based on XPath Query that I am recieving from code outside.  Selection works fine except for the root element. Here is the code that i use for element selection

```
    NameTable nameTable = new NameTable();
    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(nameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("n1", "http://test.com/types");
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("n2", "http://test.com/value");

    var xpathQueryN1 = "//n1:data";
    var xpathQueryN2 = "//n2:value";

    var elementN1 = xmlContent.XPathSelectElement(xpathQueryN1, nsmgr);
    var elementN2 = xmlContent.XPathSelectElement(xpathQueryN2, nsmgr);
```

the first **xpathQuery** will return `null` and the second one will return an element. I've also tried queries like

```
var xpathQueryN1 = "./n1:data";
var xpathQueryN1 = "n1:data";
```

But neither of them will return `data` element. The only way is to use

```
var xpathQueryN1 = ".";
```

Why explicit xpath to `n1:data` is not working?

Comment: I just tried your code and the `//n1:data` path worked fine for me.  What type is `xmlContent`?  I used a `XDocument`.  If you load into a `XElement` instead then that's your problem.

Comment: It was exactly the case. I've loaded it into `XElement` first time. With `XDocument` everything works like it should. Thanks a lot! By the way why `XDocument` and `XElement` have different `XPath` behaviour regarding the root selection?

Comment: I'm not sure, which is why I didn't add an answer.